# How to prevent 404 error when retrieving an image from my static folder

Tags: python, django

My Django project includes a company logo which is stored inside the static folder and displayed in the navbar on each page. The logo displays on some pages, but for some reason it returns a 404 error on others.

I can't spot any correlation between the pages that return a 404. Does anybody have any idea why I've encountered this problem?

```
# base.html

<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">
  <img src="../static/img/acceler8_logo.png" id="acc-logo">
</a>

# settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
```

Comment: Please use the `{% static ... %}` template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `../static/img/...` is a [*relative* path [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths). That means that a URL like `host.com/foo/` will redirect to `host.com/static/img/...`, but `host.com/foo/bar/` will redirect to `host.com/foo/static/img`.

It is therefore *not* a good idea to use relative paths. In fact it is not good to hardcode URLs anyway. Django has a [**`{% static ... %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}">
  <img src="{% static 'img/acceler8_logo.png' %}" id="acc-logo">
</a>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks very much!